# iphone paypal credit card processing api

Tags: iphone, paypal, credit-card

I want to implement credit card processing with paypal api in my iphone app. I know there is a paypal api for iphone  on www.x.com  but that is only for express checkout through paypal account and I cannot find anything for credit card processing, such that user enters his credit card details and payment occurs.

Please let me know the exact link for api or is there any other method

Answer (score 1):

Apple will most probably reject app which uses payment mechanism other than In App Purchase. The option you have is implement [Apple's In App Purchase](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

This are tutorial links for In App Purchase :

1) http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

2) http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/

Comment: No. Apple allows other payment option for purchase of other goods other than digital goods.. and there are lots of such apps already in App Store ...